# Ricci curvature is symmetric bilinear form: Why $T_pM \times T_pM \to T_pM$ and not $T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb R$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, vector-bundles, curvature

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

I refer to [Section 22.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6hql.png) and [Section 22.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQSEe.png).

Why do we have, in [Section 22.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQSEe.png), that $\text{Ric}: T_pM \times T_pM \to T_pM$, instead of $\text{Ric}: T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb R$?

Based on [Section 22.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6hql.png), I understand Ricci curvature to assign two tangent vectors at $p$ (two elements of $T_pM$) to the trace of an endomorphism. This trace is a real number, depending only on the point $p$ and on the choice of $\nabla$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381174/is-ricci-curvature-or-riemann-curvature-tensor-defined-for-the-riemannian-connec)). Perhaps I missed that there's some assignment of the two tangent vectors to a third tangent vector.

Comment: I think this is just a typo. As you write, the Ricci curvature at $p$ is a scalar-valued bilinear form $T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb R.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Again I say: Thanks! You can answer if you want.